# Postman (and python eve) providing different results to same query when done in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, postman, eve

I'm developing a very light weight API using python eve, which access a mongodb database. Each document in the database has a geom field and there is a 2d sphere index on this field.

When I run this query in mongo it works perfectly and very quickly

```
db.api.aggregate({"$geoNear": {"near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-1.11, 51.69]}, "distanceField": "distance", "maxDistance": 100, "num": 2, "spherical": "true"}}).pretty()
```

But when I run this in postman it just returns everything and ignores the query

```
http://localhost:8090/data?aggregate={"$geoNear": {"near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates":  [-1.11, 51.69]}, "distanceField": "distance", "maxDistance": 100,"num": 2,"spherical": "true"}}
```

I have a basic schema set up in Eve, which partly works. It, returns only the _id but not the distance field that is created as part of the query. Although I'm running on the assumption that this will work once I have the syntax for postman correct.

```
api_shema = {'_id': {'type': 'string'},
                      'distance': {'type': 'string'}
                      }
```

I also have this item set up

```
line_info_item = {'item_title': 'line_info',
                        'resource_methods': ['GET'],
                        'schema': api_shema,
                        'datasource': {
                            'source': 'api',
                            'filter': {'_type': 'line'}
                            }
                     }
```

Finally the following domain is added

```
DOMAIN = {'line_info': line_info_item}
```

Any help with the postman query, or if you spot any errors in the rest, would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I set up the pipeline on the endpoint as per Neil's answer below but it's still ignoring the query and returning all.

```
DOMAIN = {'line_info': line_info_item,
            'aggregation': {
                'pipeline': [{
                    "$geoNear": {
                        "near": {
                            "type": "Point", 
                            "coordinates": ["$coords"]
                        },
                        "distanceField": "distance", 
                        "maxDistance": "$maxDist",
                        "num": 10,
                        "spherical": "true"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```

The postman query url is

```
http://localhost:8090/data?aggregate={"$maxDist":500, "$coords":[-1.477307, 50.931700]}
```

EDIT

Sort of working, although ignoring the schema... but guess thats a different question.

Moved the aggregation pipeline into the item and removed the square brackets around "$coords"

```
river_relate_item = {'item_title': 'line_info_item',

                        'resource_methods': ['GET'],

                        'schema': api_shema,

                        'datasource': {
                            'source': 'api',
                            'filter': {'_type': 'line'},
                            'aggregation': {'pipeline': [{'$geoNear':{'near':{'type': 'point', 'coordinates': '$coords'},'distanceField': 'distance','maxDistance': '$maxDist','num': 1, 'spherical': 'true'}}]}
                            },

                    }
```

Comment: Don't use it myself, but pretty sure from a [quick perusal of the documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#mongodb-aggregation-framework) you are actually meant to specify the "pipleline" in configuration, and not as part of the URL. The URL parameters appear to be for use in "variable substitution" instead. So it would seem logical you set up the pipeline on the endpoint, rather than pass in the whole pipeline as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Neil, but still getting the same problem of the query being ignored and all docs being returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of working, although ignoring the schema... but guess thats a different question.

Moved the aggregation pipeline into the item and removed the square brackets around "$coords"

```
river_relate_item = {'item_title': 'line_info_item',

                        'resource_methods': ['GET'],

                        'schema': api_shema,

                        'datasource': {
                            'source': 'api',
                            'filter': {'_type': 'line'},
                            'aggregation': {'pipeline': [{'$geoNear':{'near':{'type': 'point', 'coordinates': '$coords'},'distanceField': 'distance','maxDistance': '$maxDist','num': 1, 'spherical': 'true'}}]}
                            },

                    }
```